# Scheme lambda reduction improvement

Tags: scheme, lambda-calculus

I am rewriting this questions since it was poorly formed .

```
(define (reduce f)                                                        
((lambda (value) (if (equal? value f) f (reduce value)))                 
(let r ((f f) (g ()))                                                  
(cond ((not (pair? f))                                                
(if (null? g) f (if (eq? f (car g)) (cadr g) (r f (caddr g))))) 
((and (pair? (car f)) (= 2 (length f)) (eq? 'lambda (caar f)))  
(r (caddar f) (list (cadar f) (r (cadr f) g) g)))              
((and (not (null? g)) (= 3 (length f)) (eq? 'lambda (car f)))    
(cons 'lambda (r (cdr f) (list (cadr f) (gensym (cadr f)) g))))  
(else (map (lambda (x) (r x g)) f))))))                          

; (reduce '((lambda x x) 3)) ==> 3
; (reduce '((lambda x (x x)) (lambda x (lambda y (x y)))))
;   ==> (lambda #[promise 2] (lambda #[promise 3] (#[promise 2] #[promise 3])))

; Comments: f is the form to be evaluated, and g is the local assignment
; function; g has the structure (variable value g2), where g2 contains
; the rest of the assignments.  The named let function r executes one
; pass through a form.  The arguments to r are a form f, and an
; assignment function g.  Line 2: continue to process the form until
; there are no more conversions left.  Line 4 (substitution): If f is
; atomic [or if it is a promise], check to see if matches any variable
; in g and if so replace it with the new value.  Line 6 (beta
; reduction): if f has the form ((lambda variable body) argument), it is
; a lambda form being applied to an argument, so perform lambda
; conversion.  Remember to evaluate the argument too!  Line 8 (alpha
; reduction): if f has the form (lambda variable body), replace the
; variable and its free occurences in the body with a unique object to
; prevent accidental variable collision.  [In this implementation a
; unique object is constructed by building a promise.  Note that the
; identity of the original variable can be recovered if you ever care by
; forcing the promise.]  Line 10: recurse down the subparts of f.
```

I have the above code which does a lambda reduction on a lambda expression ( which is what i want). My problem here is , can someone help me rewrite this implementation(since i am not that experienced with Scheme) so that i extract from the body the part that does alpha-conversion and put it in a separate function, and the part that does the beta-reduction as well. The function reduce is recursive so , the two new created functions need to be single-step , meaning that they will convert only one bounded variable and reduce only one expression.

Comment: FYI for future visitors, this seems to be an attempt at improving [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789927/scheme-lambda-reduction). @user, in the future, in cases like this, you should edit your original post instead of posting a new question. Editing makes everything more organized, helps you get closed questions reopened and keeps you away from being question-banned.

Comment: What is cadr in the above question ?

Answer (score 1):

Your set of requirements makes it fairly clear to me that this is homework; if I'm mistaken, let me know where your constraints come from :).

It sounds to me like you need to understand the question better before you start developing the solution. The first thing you mention is alpha-conversion, and I think that's a good place to start. Can you write some examples of how you might call an alpha-conversion function, and what it might return?

Comment: Well for example in this case ((λ x (λ y (x y))) y) , we need to do alpha conversion in "(λ y (x y))" substituting y with y1 so it will result into ((λ x (λ y1 (x y1))) y) and then doing a beta-reduction on it substituting x with y and we get (λ y1 (y y1)).You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.